# Cut from column to end of line

Tags: bash, unix

I'm having a bit of an issue cutting the output up from egrep. I have output like:

```
From: First Last
From: First Last
From: First Last
```

I want to cut out the "From: " (essentially leaving the "First Last").

I tried

```
cut -d ":" -f 7
```

but the output is just a bunch of blank lines.

I would appreciate any help.

Here's the full code that I am trying to use if it helps:

```
egrep '^From:' $file | cut -d ":" -f 7
```

NOTE: I've already tested the egrep portion of the code and it works as expected.

Comment: `[insert_cmd_name] | cut -c1stChar-LastChar` gives you the middle horizontal portion of this text, ie. `tail -n1 fname.txt | cut -c3-9` would give chars 3-9 of the last line of `fname.txt`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `cut` command lines in your question specify colon-separated fields and that you want the output to consist only of field 7; since there is no 7th field in your input, the result you're getting isn't what you intend.

Since the "From:" prefix appears to be identical across all lines, you can simply cut from the 7th character onward:

```
egrep '^From:' $file | cut -c7-
```

and get the result you intend.

Answer (score 11):

you were really close.

I think you only need to replace ":" with " " as separator and add "-" after the "7": like this:

```
cut -d " " -f 2-
```

I tested and works pretty well.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because 7 is a hardcoded value.
This answer says "no matter where the first space is, just remove everything before it"

Answer (score 5):

The `-f` argument is for what fields.  Since there is only one `:` in the line, there's only two fields.  So changing `-f 7` to `-f 2-` will give you want you want.  Albeit with a leading space.

Comment: To avoid a leading space, change the field separator as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43848910/10376320

Answer (score 5):

You can combine the `egrep` and `cut` parts into one command with `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/^From: //gp' $file
```

`sed -n` turns off printing by default, and then I am using `p` in the `sed` command explicitly to print the lines I want.

Comment: The `/g` flag is not necessary if you use the beginning of line anchor. Never it will match more than once.

Comment: @Birei agreed.  I am in the bad habit of using `g` flag all the time :-(.

Comment: And if you had not specified _-n_, the _p_ flag wouldn't have been needed.

Comment: @devnull but in that case it would print the non-matching lines as well.

Comment: @Alok-- Ah! didn't realize that it was a grep in the original question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use sed:

```
sed 's/^From: *//'
```

OR awk:

```
awk -F ': *' '$1=="From"{print $2}'
```

OR `grep -oP`

```
grep -oP '^From: *\K.*'
```

Comment: I am just about to post the `grep` solution, same as yours, with `\K`... +1 yours! this saves the pipe to another process.

Comment: @Kent: Thanks but OP seems to like piped solution more :P

Comment: For my info, is there any difference between `\K` & look-arounds, like `(?<=...)` or `(?=...)`?

Comment: @anishsane: Yes there is. In most of the regex tools lookbehind cannot be of variable length and `\K` is a good way to reset previous matches.

Comment: Hmm.. thought so. But AFAIK, grep does support regex look-arounds. You need to add it in `()`, like `(?<=(^From: *)).*`. Anyway, thanks for this info :-)

Comment: @anishsane: That's what I tried to explain. In lookbehind you cannot use variable length match, hence `grep -oP '(?<=(^From: *)).*'` will return error: `grep: lookbehind assertion is not fixed length`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Bash one-liner:

```
grep ^From file.txt | while read -a cols; do echo ${cols[@]:1}; done
```

See: [Handling positional parameters](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams) at wiki.bash-hackers.org

Answer (score 0):

**cut** itself is a very handy tool in bash

> cut -d (delimiter character) -f (fields that you want as output)

a single field is given directly as -f 3 ,
range of fields can be selected as -f 5-9

so in your this particular case code would be

> egrep '^From:' $file | cut -d\ -f 2-3

the delimiter is space here and can be escaped using a **\**

-f 1 corresponds to " From " and 2-3 corresponds to " First Last "